# ApplicationUser - how do I use it? what do I need to put in my using clauses?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

I am trying to follow this tutorial but I'm stuck in the area where it tries to add ApplicationUser based code.  The roles section.

[dotnet deploy db based MVC site to azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/)

**I did include these lines:**

```
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
```

**My compile error**

`Error  1   The type or namespace name 'ApplicationUser' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   c:\users\blah\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\blah\blah\Migrations\Configuration.cs   96  38  blah`

**edit:
here's the whole snippet of code:**

```
 bool AddUserAndRole(ContactManager.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
 {
    IdentityResult ir;
    var rm = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>
        (new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
    ir = rm.Create(new IdentityRole("canEdit"));
    var um = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(
        new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
    var user = new ApplicationUser()
    {
       UserName = "user1",
    };
    ir = um.Create(user, "Passw0rd1");
    if (ir.Succeeded == false)
       return ir.Succeeded;
    ir = um.AddToRole(user.Id, "canEdit");
    return ir.Succeeded;
 }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you create an **ApplicationUser** class which inherits from **IdentityUser**? If so, did you add the namespace, in which the **ApplicationUser** class is located, to the **Configuration** class?

That are the most reasonable things for resolving this error.

Comment: I don't know.  I was following the tutorial.  The step before adding applicationUser said to add the "using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;" and "using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;" namespace.  I'm assuming that's the namespace for it but I don't know how to be certain.  I'm adding the snippet of code above.

Comment: `ApplicationUser` comes as part of the project template and it's located in `Models/IdentityModels.cs`. You need to add a `using` statement for its namespace in Configuration.cs (should be `<ProjectName>.Models`).

Comment: Thanks.  adding a using statement for <project name>.models did the trick.  I tend to name my tutorial projects whatever the hell I want to name them (instead of following tutorial naming schemes blindly) and in this case it "got me into trouble".  But I also learned a lot because of it.  So I regret nothing.

Comment: Hi could You please show your configuration.cs file . I am also getting same error not able to use identiyUser Attribute other than Default Attribute

Comment: @Neeraj Mehta this is configuration.cs `namespace MyApplication1.ApplicationDbMigrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;
    using Application1.Models; //since ApplicationUser is in IdentityModels.cs
    // For identity
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework; <...lots of code following..>`